# Move left and right div when you use the scrollTop method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

Ciao, io voglio muovere il div a destra e a sinistra in base alla posizione dello scrollbar
Potete aiutarmi?

Hello, I want to move the div to the right or left depending on the position of the scrollbar
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

hehe . you need to be a bit more .... helpful ;-)

but here's what i think you mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/pWUDJ/3/

Comment: thanks for your answer.
The position of the div is 550px from the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("div#mydiv").css({
            "left": ($(window).scrollTop() - 100) + "px"
        }).text("hello:" + $(window).scrollTop());
    }
});​
```